# Is there a function to test choice box selection in TestFX?

Tags: java, javafx, testfx

I want to test my written JavaFX GUI with TestFX. In one step there are some ChoiceBoxs that i want to test.

I have tried the following code so far:

```
this.step("fill creation view", () -> {
      this.clickOn("#receiverChoiceBox").clickOn("Max Mustermann");

      verifyThat("#receiverChoiceBox",
          ComboBoxMatchers.hasSelectedItem(this.userInformationMap.get(2)));
    });
```

However, this will result in the following error message:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: 
Expected: ComboBox has selection "xxx.model.dto.UserInformationDto@d84f7f5d"
     but: was a xxx.gui.control.xxxChoiceBox (<xxxChoiceBox[id=receiverChoiceBox, styleClass=choice-box]>)
Expected :ComboBox has selection "xxx.model.dto.UserInformationDto@d84f7f5d"
Actual   :a xxx.gui.control.xxxChoiceBox (<xxxChoiceBox[id=receiverChoiceBox, styleClass=choice-box]>)
```

I know I'm using a ComboBox Matcher, but I've tried other options before, which didn't work either. Is there a similar Matcher for ChoiceBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now solved the problem as follows:

```
verifyThat("#receiverChoiceBox", node -> this.userInformationMap.get(2).equals(((ChoiceBox)node).getValue()));
```